# Converting theano tensor types

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, theano

I have a computation graph built with Theano. It goes like this:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np

W1 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(45,32).astype('float32'), 'W1')
b1 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(32).astype('float32'), 'b1')
W2 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(32,3).astype('float32'), 'W2')
b2 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(3).astype('float32'), 'b2')

input  = T.matrix('input')
hidden = T.tanh(T.dot(input, W1)+b1)
output = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(hidden, W2)+b2)
```

Now, the mapping from a vector to a vector. However, input is set as a matrix type so I can pass many vectors through the mapping simultaneously. I'm doing some machine learning and this makes the learning phase more efficient.

The problem is that after the learning phase, I'd like to view the mapping as vector to vector so I can compute:

```
jac = theano.gradient.jacobian(output, wrt=input)
```

`jacobian` complains that input is not `TensorType(float32, vector)`. Is there a way I can change the input tensor type without rebuilding the whole computation graph?

Comment: Unable to answer this question without a concrete example -- in principle you can reshape tensors as easily as you can reshape numpy arrays. Same goes for slicing. You will need either one of these operations, if I understand correctly. `input.reshape((-1,))` makes a long vector. `input[:, 0]` selects the first column. HTH

Comment: The problem with using the reshaped or flattened tensor in the jacobian call is that this reshaped tensor is not part of the computation graph of `output`. The flow is input => stuff => output. Is it possible to insert the reshape between input and "stuff"?

Comment: I don't know. But if we had a working example, we could find out :)

Comment: I added an example computation graph. This graph in general is built inside an object according to user arguments. So this graph does not always look exactly like this. Nonetheless, `input` is always a matrix, but the inherent function being modeled is vector to vector. What I'm asking is if the `TensorType` of `input` can be changed after this graph is built.

Comment: In theano `0.6.0` I do not get this error. However, I do get one due to the shape of the output, but `jac = theano.gradient.jacobian(output.flatten(), wrt=input)` fixes that and should be OK for you if you want to evaluate this one image at a time. If this doesn't work for you, you can do `input=T.fvector()` and then reshape it to a matrix in "hidden" using `hidden = T.tanh(T.dot(input.reshape((-1, W1.shape[0])), W1)+b1)`. (I'm curious - is this for manipulating input samples? :)). Could you correct the typos in the expressions for `b1` and `b2`?

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned that flattening `output` was one issue. This was an easy fix since `output` is at the end of the computation chain. I was still receiving the error on `0.6.0` with regards to `input`'s shape, but when I tried on a separate install on a separate machine with version `0.6.0.dev-RELEASE`, `jacobian` works fine with `output.flatten()` and `input` as `TensorType(float32, matrix)`. I'm guessing this was a recent update, although I'm not sure why this would work in your `0.6.0` but not mine.

Comment: To address your second question ("is this for manipulating input samples?"), I'm training neural networks and inspecting properties of the network after parameters have been learned. For the learning phase, it is more efficient to pass inputs in batches (so the `input` should be a matrix). Afterwards I'd like to measure the Jacobian of the network about a point. I couldn't do this in my `0.6.0` without setting `input` as a vector type and rebuilding the whole computation chain.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this a possible solution:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np

W1 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(45,32).astype('float32'), 'W1')
b1 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(32).astype('float32'), 'b1')
W2 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(32,3).astype('float32'), 'W2')
b2 = theano.shared( np.random.rand(3).astype('float32'), 'b2')

input  = T.vector('input') # it will be reshaped!
hidden = T.tanh(T.dot(input.reshape((-1, 45)), W1)+b1)
output = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(hidden, W2)+b2)

#Here comes the trick
jac = theano.gradient.jacobian(output.reshape((-1,)), wrt=input).reshape((-1, 45, 3))
```

In this way `jac.eval({input: np.random.rand(10*45)}).shape` will result `(100, 45, 3)`!

The problem is that it calculates the derivative across the batch index. So in theory the first `1x45` number can effect all the `10x3` outputs (in a batch of length 10).

For that, there are several solutions.
You could take the diagonal across the first two axes, but unfortunately [Theano does not implement it](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nlinalg.py#L193), [numpy does](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)!

I think it can be done with a `scan`, but this is an other matter.